AWS DMS migration Premigration assessment possible bug on "Validate if the timeout values are appropriate for a MySQL source or target"
So I have:

source: AWS Lightsail DB MySQL on version 8.0.35
target: AWS Aurora MySQL 3.07.0 (8.0.36)

And one Assessment is constantly failing "Validate if the timeout values are appropriate for a MySQL source or target"
Where on results for it says:

Net Read Timeout: 30
Net Write Timeout: 60
Wait Timeout: 28800
Message: "Net read, net write and wait timeouts must be greater than 5 minutes for DMS target database to prevent connection drops while replicating. Please increase the timeouts to at least 300 seconds"

Screenshot of AWS Premigration assessment error output
The problem is:

I already have set those first 2 timeouts to 600 on parameters group of target db
and also on both source and target endpoints with: {"AfterConnectScript": "SET net_read_timeout=600; SET net_write_timeout=600; SET replica_net_timeout=600; SET slave_net_timeout=600;"}

Also tried a couple of other fields like replica_net_timeout and slave_net_timeout, but that too did not solve the issue so I am stuck.
Appreciate any help or insights, thanks!
Also posted on: https://repost.aws/questions/QU0A8mOoYkSWqkflydm2G97g/aws-dms-migration-premigration-assessment-possible-bug
